# Java Collection framework, Arraylist working with objects

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

Here is starting Branch Class:

```
package com.sherzod;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Branch {
    private String branchName;
    private ArrayList<Customer> customer;

    public Branch(String branchName) {
        this.branchName = branchName;
        this.customer = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getBranchName() {
        return branchName;
    }

    public ArrayList<Customer> getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    **public Customer findCustomer(String name){
        for (int i=0; i<this.customer.size(); i++){
            Customer checkedCustomer = this.customer.get(i);
            if(checkedCustomer.equals(name)){
                return checkedCustomer;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }**
}
```

Here is starting Customer Class:

```
package com.sherzod;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Customer {
    private String customerName;
    private ArrayList<Double> transactions;

    public Customer(String customerName) {
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.transactions = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public String getCustomerName() {
        return customerName;
    }

    public ArrayList<Double> getTransactions() {
        return transactions;
    }

    public void addTransaction(double amount){
        transactions.add(amount);
    }
}
```

question is how come we create a method which is return (as a boolean) type "Customer" object?
even if I didn't extend Customer class from Branches still code works, no errors.
so means Customer has a relationship with Branch class because of I am initializing Customer Arraylist in the Branch class? I am learning java since 8 month so much confusing now..

Comment: *question is how come we create a method which is return (as a boolean) type "Customer" object?* - could you rephrase what you want to ask? it is really difficult to understand what your question is.

Comment: I mean, usually if we want to return something, we go like this: 
"public (int, double, String etc.,) methodName(){}" right?

But in the Branch class I am writing an method like: 
"public Customer findCustomer()"

and findCustomer is returning an object? This part i don't get  it

Comment: ..and? what is your question then? you want your method to return `boolean`? or..? formulate the Question, please.

Comment: can you explain me from where we got this "findCustomer" method? and what is returning data type?

Comment: Return type of `public Customer findCustomer(String name)` is `Customer` as you evidently can see this. I have no clue *from where* you got this method.

Comment: all right thx anyway, i think i am bit unclear with my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a java class in a package you don't need to import the other public classes in the same package.
i.e. `Customer` class doesn't need to be imported in `Branch` class (as both are part of `com.sherzod`), unlike `ArrayList` which is part of `java.util` package.

For:

```
even if I didn't extend Customer class from Branches still code works, no errors.
```

Inheritance is a different subject. Relation b/w Branches and Customer classes is that they are in the same package, they don't need to have a parent child relation